# Can you cast Sanctuary through total cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover, line-of-effect

Sanctuary says:

> You ward a creature within range against attack. Until the spell ends, any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack or a harmful spell must first make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or lose the attack or spell. This spell doesn't protect the warded creature from area effects, such as the explosion of a fireball.

Can you cast it on a target within range but behind total cover?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the target can be behind total cover with regard to an enemy, but not behind total cover with regard to you, and in most cases it would be reasonable to signal an ally to make part of their body visible to you to, but not to enemies to get around this limitation.

Answer (score 15):

### No

> **[A Clear Path to the Target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget)**
>
> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind **total cover**. If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction.

The Sanctuary spell does not have a specific rule that overrides the general rule.